# Error compiling C++ code with Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I'm trying to pass the value using parameter from Objective c class to C++ class. Below is the code I'm using to pass the value:-

```
std::string cpp_str([str UTF8String], [str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
wrapped.ExampleMethod(cpp_str);
```

While compiling in Xcode its showing the below error:-

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"Test::ExampleMethod(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  -[ViewController exampleMethodWithString:] in ViewController.ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please give reply that how should I do this?

Comment: Hold on, if you aren't using Objective-C++ then the compiler wouldn't even know what `std::string` was.  So I don't believe the tags.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, #trojanfoe im using the Compiler Objective-C++ in my app. but still its showing above error.

Comment: You have tagged this "objective-c".  That is wrong.  it should be "objective-c++".  Please fix.

Comment: Linker tells that you haven't implemented `Test::ExampleMethod`. `Objective-C` isn't involved at all.